# how to paste string in R

Tags: r

I want to paste 4 strings together, the code is here:

```
urlstring<-"lee/"
code<-read.csv("D:\\list.csv",sep="\n",head=FALSE)
for(y in code){count<-1
           while(count<3){
             mydate<-Sys.Date()-count
             filename<-paste(urlstring,mydate,"&symbol=",y,sep="")
             print(filename)
             count<-count+1
           }
         }
```

my question is why the output is, date is changing firstly :

```
lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=1    
lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=2    
lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=1    
lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=2
```

but  in my opinion,the result should be this,the value of code should be changed   firstly:

```
lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=1    
lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=1    
lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=2    
lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=2
```

Comment: I get your "desired" result if `code <- 1:2`.

Comment: We do not have the `list.csv` file. You need to provide us the `code` object, or the `csv` file. Without that, we cannot reproduce your problem and help you with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @mnel said. for `code = 1:2` your code yields the correct results. Note that the nested for-while loop is not needed, a vectorized solution uses less code is and is often faster:

```
code = rep(1:2, each = 2)
mydate = Sys.Date() - code
sprintf('lee/date=%s&symbol=%d', mydate, code)
[1] "lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=1" "lee/date=2013-11-14&symbol=1"
[3] "lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=2" "lee/date=2013-11-13&symbol=2"
```

This solution is called vectorized because when `sprintf` is used with vectors, the result is also a vector, without explicitily using a loop.